# Deselecting the selected row in Xamarin forms list view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view. On Tapping the selected row, how do I deselect? If I select a different row which is not selected, it must select it. How do I do this? Thanks

```
  <ListView x:Name="DimensionListView" HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"  SeparatorVisibility="Default" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
```

Comment: You mean highlighting the selected item of listview?

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to deselect the item which is selected when you click it again ?

If yes,you could check below:

```
<ListView x:Name="DimensionListView" HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"  SeparatorVisibility="Default" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
```

in the page.xaml.cs:

```
int preIndex = -1;


private void OnItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (preIndex == e.ItemIndex)
        {
            DimensionListView.SelectedItem = null;
            preIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            preIndex = e.ItemIndex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ListView x:Name="DimensionListView" HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"  SeparatorVisibility="Default" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
```

Your on ItemSelected handler:

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (DimensionListView.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }   

        DimensionListView.SelectedItem = null;    
    }
```